# Calling C# method from VBA using COM Interop

Tags: vba, com-interop

By refering [this](https://www.geeksengine.com/article/create-dll.html), I was able to attach Entities.tlb file to VBA. But I couldn't able to create an instance from the classes in C#. This is my code,

C# class

```
namespace Entities
{
    [Guid("1558C766-44DA-4DA5-BF2F-CBD6804E7E21")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface ITools
    {
        ABC GetABC();

    }

    [Guid("514719AC-E137-4FCA-82AF-73E4025A8625")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Tools : ITools
    {
        public Tools()
        {

        }

        public methods ...
    }
}
```

From VBA,

```
Dim objElement As New Entities.Tools
```

This caused Error : Invalid Use Of New Key Word

And also in VBA object browser,for attached Entities.tlb it shows all the classes under Entities namespace. But It's not showing any method inside those classes.

How can I create a instance of Tools class in VBA and access methods in Tools class from VBA ?

Comment: You use InterfaceIsIDispatch to hide a bug in the interface.  That merely caused new problems.  I could guess why you did this, but there's very little point to that when you can just tell us.

Answer (score -2):

Delete the constructor.  VBA can't use them and c# will implement the default constructor transparently..

Then try in the class

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ITools))]
```

and in the interface

Just

```
[ComVisible(true)]
```

Then in VBA

```
Dim objElement as Tools
set objElement = new Tools
```

I have a C# class that I access from VBA and this is the only way I've found that gives intellisense in VBA and still allows items such as GetEnumerator to work correctly.

[Kvp C# dictionary wrapper for VBA](https://github.com/SteveLaycock/Kvp)

You should also be aware that if you have an indexer in your class then the .Item[x] syntax will only work in if you choose to not have intellisense.  If you have intellisense then then the use of .Item[x]=value will generate a VBA error due toa bug in how the intermediate language is constructed for the indexer.